# Delete windows completely and install ubuntu on SSD

Tags: 19.10

Currently I have Kubunut 19.10 with windows dualboot and I would like to completely remove Windows and change from HDD to SSD without losing any data at Kubuntu. What would be the "receipt" for that?  Should I first deinstall windows and then change everything to SSD or should I make it in another way?

Comment: If UEFI system, be sure to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI You now also do not need a swap partition as Ubuntu by default uses swap file. But if it finds swap on HDD, it will use that. Click on it and say do not use if that is the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any possible (and simple) way to delete my Windows partitions and extend my Ubuntu partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184873/is-there-any-possible-and-simple-way-to-delete-my-windows-partitions-and-exten)

Comment: Oh, so this won't be an easy game, like I thought, to make this ^^

Comment: and is it hard to deinstall windows, and even recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for 19.10 [ends July 2020.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) As this is the case at this point you might wish to consider simply installing 20.04 on the SSD and installing the applications you are used to using (if available for 20.04).  You can [generate a list of currently installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) and use that as a guide to install them. You could then [mount your old HDD and use rsync or similar to duplicate the files in your HDD home directory to your SSD.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install Kubuntu to the SSD.

Step 2: Boot from the SSD. Mount the HDD and copy your data over.

There are lots of details involved in each step, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First install Kubuntu (19.10 although you might want to consider 20.04 as @Elder Geek pointed out). Then use deja dup to backup your data on your hard drive and then transfer the backup and restore it to your SSD. You can just write a script to install all the programs that you use and then execute that script on your new SSD.

To list all installed programs

```
apt list --installed
```

See this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519/how-do-i-write-an-application-install-shell-script) for information on how to write a script.